# Powerbi - working with three filters with different logic on a single page

Tags: filter, powerbi

i want to crete a page that will show top n entity , but the difficulty is that 
the page have to work along three different filters , and each filters have data from differnt columns of an excel sheet.
Example - i have to show top n (any number ) employee name with salary on the basis of age , gender , work exp in a vertical bar view.
we have filter on age, work ex ,gender and also the filter should work in a hierarchy manner as well as individaully .It should give top n salary (emp name ) female employee if we select only gender filter . after that if we select age 20 then it should give top n salary of employee who are female and age is 20 . data should change accordingly on selection of filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a visual level filter for the data visualization (e.g. table).

For example, filter on the key showing the top 10 salary only.

[image: visual level filter]

Then, you can set the three different filters you want on the page and the data in the visualization will change accordingly.

Without filter selected:
[image: without filter selected]

With filter selected:
[image: with filter selected]

Comment: soln is correct but ,this should be in the form of vertical bars .Showing top n values as per filter selected .

Comment: @SagarRajSingh: Edited. The screenshots are just an example. It works with most of the data visualizations.